# Azure Web App returns binary file 'modified' with incorrect size

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure web app that returns a binary file using FileStreamResult. Works fine...

```
FileStreamResult fsr = File(blobStream, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, "testfile.bin");
return fsr;
```

I copied this code to another web app, returning the exact same blob item, and it returns a 'corrupted' file that is almost 2x larger (65K vs 117K). Both apps are using the same version of .Net, the same Azure account, the same Azure storage account, the response headers are the same...but something must be different!

Update: The FileStreamResult has the correct data/size in the buffer. If I copy the data out of the FileStream (before returning), it's OK. So the FileStreamResult is correct; the problem happens when the response is generated. Something with how FileStreamResult is converted. I've also tried ActionResult, same problem.

Update 2: Still can't figure it out but...it's swapping out the non-UTF-8 chars with the EF BF BD unicode replacement characters. I'm not sure why. I thought the content type of application/octet-stream would indicate the data is not interpreted. Also can't find why one web app does this but the other does not.

Comment: Is this blob public? If not, does your new app service have appropriate access?

Comment: Yep, the blob is public. The CORS settings are basically *. Accessing the blob url directly works fine. Only when using FileStreamResult does it get "corrupted". Yet FileStreamResult works on the other app service. Using Postman to access the endpoints yields the same response headers, including Server version, MVC version, .NET, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could update the package `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore` to the latest version `4.0.1`.

Here is a similar [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/1605) you could refer to.

Comment: Well, I'm not using Swashbuckle/Swagger anywhere in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Finally success...turns out there was an ActionFilterAttribute on the base controller that was forcing the encoding.